# Google Apps Script hideRow() stops the for loop

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to loop through a range showing only those rows that match a selected cell value, but the loop stops after executing the first hide/unhide. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var statutSlct = e.range;
 var sh=statutSlct.getSheet();
  var tableau = sh.getRange("Tableau");
  var numRows = tableau.getNumRows();
  var statutCol = 8;
  //statutSlct.setNote(e.value + numRows);

  if(sh.getName()=='Suivis' && statutSlct.columnStart==statutCol && statutSlct.rowStart==1){
    if(e.value=="TOUT"){
      var filter = tableau.getFilter();
      if (filter !== null) {
        filter.remove()     
      }
    };
    for (let j = 1; j <= numRows; j++) {
      var cell = tableau.getCell(j, statutCol)
      if (cell !== null) {
        if (cell.getValue() == e.value || e.value == "TOUT") {
          cell.setNote("show " + cell.getValue() + j + " " + e.value + numRows);
          sh.unhideRow.row(cell);
        }
        else {
          cell.setNote("hide " + cell.getValue() + j + " " + e.value + numRows);
          sh.hideRow.row(cell);
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have so many rows that the onEdit just times out after 30 it reaches 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Found the execution log and hideRow(cell) was the correct syntax.